# How to fix the dependent REST API call in protractor

Tags: node.js, typescript, request, protractor

Have written a protractor spec file in typescript. containing two it blocks. Each IT block calls one POST REST API. First one is calling authentication API which returns cookies values if successfully authenticated. The second API need this authenticated cookie to be set in request header along with JSON payload.

The issue is with first-run only authentication API works and it returns the cookie but it does not create the resource. The resource is getting created if I run once again.

Below is my spec file:

```
import { Utility } from "../../../commonLibraries/utility";
describe("Test API calls", ()=>{
    let utility = new Utility();
    let request = require('request');
    let cookiesValue: any;
    let cookie_value: any;
    let uniqueID = utility.getUniqueUserName();

    it("Login using API", ()=>{
        cookie_value = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            request.post('https://www.myserver.com/web/json/login',{
                form: {
                username: 'xxxxxxx',
                password: 'xxxxxxx'
                },
                rejectUnauthorized:false,
                headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }, (error, httpResopnse, body)=>{
                if(error){
                    console.log("Error: ", error);
                    reject(error);
                }
                cookiesValue = httpResopnse.headers['set-cookie'][1];
                resolve(cookiesValue);
            });
        });
    });

    it("Create Resource", ()=>{
        console.log(accessioningID)
        cookie_value.then((data1)=>{

            const json_data = {
                "Resource": {
                    "Id": null,
                    "accId": accessioningID,
                    "someData": "Some Data here"
                }
            };
            console.log(data1);
            request.post( {uri: 'https://www.myserver.com/web/json/resource', 
                            body: JSON.stringify(json_data),
                            rejectUnauthorized:false,
                            headers:{
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'Cookie': data1
                            },
                }, (error, httpResopnse, body)=>{
                if(error){
                    console.log("Error: ", error);
                }
                //console.log("Response: ", httpResopnse.statusCode);
                console.log("Response: ", httpResopnse);
                console.log("Body ", body)
            });
       });
    });
});
```

It's should execute both APIs and resource should be created.

Comment: I do believe `it` blocks is only for actual tests, so you should move the auth process into `beforeAll` block, otherwise protractor may launch `it` blocks in parallel, it is not a stable solution

Comment: to previous comment - `it` blocks never run in parallel. It's a matter of personal choice

Comment: When you say 'if I run once again', do you mean you run again the whole spec file?

Comment: @Sergey - Yes, I need to re-run the whole script for creating the resource

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the docs for request (found here)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

If you'd like request to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface for request. I have experienced some unpredictable behavior involving API responses when trying to make API calls using request with promises and async/await. I used request-promise instead (https://github.com/request/request-promise), which is built upon request.

Comment: dearly3 - have tried request-promise in this for the second API it throws a un-authenticated error. Had checked the values of the cookie it was getting set to previous APIs return.